# How to check if parameter passed into SQL is null and return rows that match the parameter

Tags: sql

I want to pass a parameter of list of strings of product types into my SQL statement and want it to check if it is null or not and select all the rows where the productType and or color matches the rows. I'm essentially trying to implement filters.

```
SELECT productName, productType, cost, color  
  FROM inventory 
  WHERE CASE(
         WHEN( (productType IN :typeList) IS NOT NULL 
         THEN (SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE productType IN 
         :typeList)
         WHEN(color in :colors) IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT * FROM 
         inventory WHERE color IN:typeList)
         END
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with:

```
SELECT productName, productType, cost  
 FROM inventory 
WHERE productType IN :typeLIST
```

Comment: The query is being used to implement filters. The parameters I want to pass in are the filter types. I want it to check if there filters(parameters with values) passed in and query based on that and return the entire table if there are no parameters passed in.